# Unity3D Vive throw objects when let go of

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am attempting to make a physics sandbox-type game for the Vive, but the velocity of an object is completely reset and just begins falling when you let go of an object you were previously holding, making throwing impossible.
The system I am using currently will disable gravity on an object, and disable colliders of on an object when you pick it up. It will also child the object to your controller, making it like holding the object. When you let go of the button to release the object, it will enable gravity, enable colliders, and then set its parent object to null. This works to pick up and release an object, but it does not work at all for throwing objects. I have played around with timing and order of the components of the code, and nothing works.
Is there any way to find the velocity of an object and the directional velocity, without the object using gravity? Velocity doesn't work if gravity is disabled.

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class WandController : MonoBehaviour
{
//Basic Controller tracking stuff
private Valve.VR.EVRButtonId gripButton = Valve.VR.EVRButtonId.k_EButton_Grip;
public bool gripButtonDown = false;
public bool gripButtonUp = false;
public bool gripButtonPressed = false;

private Valve.VR.EVRButtonId triggerButton = Valve.VR.EVRButtonId.k_EButton_SteamVR_Trigger;
public bool triggerButtonDown = false;
public bool triggerButtonUp = false;
public bool triggerButtonPressed = false;

private SteamVR_Controller.Device controller { get { return SteamVR_Controller.Input((int)trackedObj.index); } }
private SteamVR_TrackedObject trackedObj;

//Game Variables
public GameObject wouldSelect; //What is in the select zone, has tiny script for the zone that sets the newest triggerenter to this variable
public GameObject isHolding; //When you hold something, it goes from wouldselect to isholding
public bool holding = false;
public GameObject holdingZone; //The holding zone, also where objects go if they are picked up

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    trackedObj = GetComponent<SteamVR_TrackedObject>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    //Basic Controller configuration  & button management stuff
    if (controller == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Controller not initialized");
        return;
    }
    gripButtonDown = controller.GetPressDown(gripButton);
    gripButtonUp = controller.GetPressUp(gripButton);
    gripButtonPressed = controller.GetPress(gripButton);

    triggerButtonDown = controller.GetPressDown(triggerButton);
    triggerButtonUp = controller.GetPressUp(triggerButton);
    triggerButtonPressed = controller.GetPress(triggerButton);
    if (gripButtonDown)
    {
        Debug.Log("Grip Button was just pressed");
    }
    if (gripButtonUp)
    {
        Debug.Log("Grip Button was just unpressed");
    }
    if (triggerButtonDown)
    {
        Debug.Log("Trigger Button was just pressed");
    }
    if (triggerButtonUp)
    {
        Debug.Log("Trigger Button was just unpressed");
    }

    //Calling void that allows you to grab
    CanGrab();
}

void CanGrab ()
{
    if(wouldSelect != null && wouldSelect.tag == "Object" && triggerButtonDown == true && holding == false)
    {
        wouldSelect.GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;
        wouldSelect.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
        isHolding = wouldSelect;
        wouldSelect.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
        wouldSelect.transform.position = holdingZone.transform.position;
        holding = true;
    }
    if(holding == true && triggerButtonUp == true)
    {
        wouldSelect.GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = true;
        isHolding.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = true;
        isHolding.transform.SetParent(null);
        holding = false;
        wouldSelect = null;
        isHolding = null;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and solved it by:

- tracking the position of the object at every frame, and storing it as lastPosition
- when the object is let go, using (transform.position - lastPosition) to give me a rough estimate of the velocity of that object

From there, you can add an impulse force if you have a rigidbody, etc, I found a thread with some details on the various ways Unity does it -- http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/696068/difference-between-forcemodeforceaccelerationimpul.html

Comment: To make the estimate feel less rough, you can store the last e.g. 60 frames and average the result. This will help ease over variation in framerate.

Comment: this system might have something useful also "NewtonVR: Physics-based interaction on the Vive (Part 1)" : http://www.vrinflux.com/newton-vr-physics-based-interaction-on-the-vive/

Comment: yes good suggestion Xarbrough -- in my experience averaging 3 frames is better than 60. if you average too far back, you don't get as much pop in your motion. if you want to be better, you can make a weighted average with more weight on the more recent samples. if you want to be really good about it, you could fit a second-order curve to the latest samples in which case going up to 60 can't hurt. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I did a number of throwing mechanics in VR using the same parameters you had (Setting the object as a child of your controller, disabling gravity, disabling colliders).

The way I did it was to **record the position of the object on the previous and current frame**, and take the difference between them as the velocity. However, there are three main factors to consider:

1. There might be some **jitter in the tracking of the controller**, and sometimes the object does not fly in the direction of throw.
2. There might be a **lag time between the user pressing/letting go** of the throwing button and the button press/release getting recorded, and so the object is thrown only towards the falling arc of the throw. (This happens a lot in my playtests)
3. There is a peak force during a throw during which an object gains the most velocity for its flight, and sometimes people let go of the object a split second after. This is rather inconsequential, but you should definitely consider if you want very realistic throwing (Take a look at The Lab demo and you will know what I mean)

My implementation:

1. **Record the last x frames** (for me the sweet spot is between 10-15 frames) for the object's position.
2. Take the difference in the first and last frame in the window and use that to calculate the velocity.

   transform.velocity = position[n] - position[0];
3. If I want a slightly more accurate implementation, I'll calculate the force of the throw by taking the differences in velocities for adjacent frames. If there is a time window between the peak force and the release of the object, do not take the velocities in the later half of the window. 
   For example, if I decide to record the last 10 frames of a throw, and there are 4 frames between the peak force and the release, I will take frame current-12 to current-2, instead of frame current-10 to current for the velocity.